# how to full outer join with 3 tables in sql?

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables :

table1 : "vw_dimserver" :[ServerKey,ServerNm,ServerCurrentAssignedToNm] for example : [1234,hasgapp0108,Aya]

table2 "vw_DimWorker" : [WorkerEmailNm, WorkerIdsid] . for example : [Aya, akhate] , [Genna,gshysh] , [mish,mishka] (it's like name and username)

table3 "vw_FactHardwareAssetContact" : [ServerKey,HardwareAssetWorkerKey, HardwareAssetContactTypeNm]. for example : [1234,Aya,support]
[1234,Genna,Customer] 
[1234,Mish,patch] ( it's server key and the name of the contact and the contact type, if it's support or customer or patch)

I need the output to be in one row: 
[ServerNm,WorkerIdsid of the ServerCurrentAssignedToNm, WorkerIdsid  of the Customer, WorkerIdsid of the support]
[hasgapp0108,akhate,gshysh,mishka]

Now I need joins with the usernames table to get the username of each user.
I did it with Full outer join.

the code is :

SELECT
    vw_dimserver.ServerNm as hostname ,
    (vw_DimWorker1.WorkerIdsid) as username,
    (vw_DimWorker2.WorkerIdsid) as [Primary Support Contact],
     (vw_DimWorker3.WorkerIdsid) as [Primary Customer Contact]

```
from vw_dimserver
        inner join vw_FactHardwareAssetContact  on vw_dimserver.ServerKey = vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetKey 
    inner join vw_DimWorker as vw_DimWorker1  on  vw_DimWorker1.WorkerEmailNm = vw_dimserver.ServerCurrentAssignedToNm  
    full outer join  vw_DimWorker as  vw_DimWorker2 on   CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )  = vw_DimWorker2.workerWWID and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Support' and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '1'  and( vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey is not NULL)
   full outer  join   vw_DimWorker as  vw_DimWorker3 on   CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )  = vw_DimWorker3.workerWWID and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Customer' and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '1' and( vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey is not NULL)
where vw_dimserver.ServerNm ='hasgapp0108'   and (vw_DimWorker2.workerWWID is  not null or vw_DimWorker3.workerWWID is not null ) and ( ServerCurrentSubStatusCd != 'duplicate_error' or ServerCurrentSubStatusCd is NULL )
```

The output is two rows:

[hostname   username    Support Customer ]

[hasgapp0108    akhate      NULL    gshysh],

[hasgapp0108    akhate      akhate  NULL]

and I need it to be one row :

[hostname   username    Support Customer]

[hasgapp0108    akhate      akhate  gshysh]

My manager didn't accept the solutaion :

```
select max(username1),max(username2)...
```

I need to do it with joins.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: in your question you have only 2 tables  not 3  ..

Comment: I edit my post , please see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SELECT vw_dimserver.ServerNm as hostname , (vw_DimWorker1.WorkerIdsid) as username, (vw_DimWorker2.WorkerIdsid) as [Primary Support Contact], (vw_DimWorker3.WorkerIdsid) as [Primary Customer Contact]

from vw_dimserver

full outer join vw_FactHardwareAssetContact as vw_FactHardwareAssetContact1 
    on (vw_dimserver.ServerKey = vw_FactHardwareAssetContact1.HardwareAssetKey and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact1.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Support' and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact1.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '1'  )

full outer join vw_DimWorker as vw_DimWorker1 on  CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact1.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )   =  vw_DimWorker1.workerWWID

full outer  join vw_DimWorker as assings  on  assings.WorkerEmailNm = vw_dimserver.ServerCurrentAssignedToNm

full outer join vw_FactHardwareAssetContact as vw_FactHardwareAssetContact2 on (vw_dimserver.ServerKey = vw_FactHardwareAssetContact2.HardwareAssetKey and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact2.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Customer'  and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact2.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '1' )

full outer join vw_DimWorker as vw_DimWorker2 on  CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact2.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )   =  vw_DimWorker2.workerWWID

full OUTER join vw_FactHardwareAssetContact as vw_FactHardwareAssetContact11 on (vw_dimserver.ServerKey = vw_FactHardwareAssetContact11.HardwareAssetKey and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact11.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Support' and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact11.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '0'  )

full outer  join vw_DimWorker as vw_DimWorker11 on  CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact11.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )   =  vw_DimWorker11.workerWWID

full OUTER join vw_FactHardwareAssetContact as vw_FactHardwareAssetContact22 on (vw_dimserver.ServerKey = vw_FactHardwareAssetContact22.HardwareAssetKey and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact22.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Customer' and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact11.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '0'  )

full outer  join vw_DimWorker as vw_DimWorker22 on  CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact22.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )   =  vw_DimWorker22.workerWWID

Answer (score 0):

Try this with inner join and group_concat:

```
    SELECT vw_dimserver.ServerNm as hostname , group_concat(vw_DimWorker1.WorkerIdsid) as username, group_concat(vw_DimWorker2.WorkerIdsid) as [Primary Support Contact], group_concat(vw_DimWorker3.WorkerIdsid) as [Primary Customer Contact]

from vw_dimserver
        inner join vw_FactHardwareAssetContact  on vw_dimserver.ServerKey = vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetKey 
    inner join vw_DimWorker as vw_DimWorker1  on  vw_DimWorker1.WorkerEmailNm = vw_dimserver.ServerCurrentAssignedToNm  
    full outer join  vw_DimWorker as  vw_DimWorker2 on   CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )  = vw_DimWorker2.workerWWID and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Support' and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '1'  and( vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey is not NULL)
   full outer  join   vw_DimWorker as  vw_DimWorker3 on   CONVERT(varchar(11),vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey )  = vw_DimWorker3.workerWWID and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetContactTypeNm = 'Customer' and vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetPrimaryInd = '1' and( vw_FactHardwareAssetContact.HardwareAssetWorkerKey is not NULL)
where vw_dimserver.ServerNm ='hasgapp0108'   and (vw_DimWorker2.workerWWID is  not null or vw_DimWorker3.worker
group by vw_dimserver.ServerNm
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an inner join if you need  only matching result

```
    SELECT
      s.ServerKey,
      s.ServerNm,
      group_concat(w.WorkerIdsid)
    FROM vw_dimserver s
    INNER JOIN vw_FactHardwareAssetContact c
      ON s.ServerKey = c.ServerKey
    INNER JOIN vw_DimWorker w
      ON c.HardwareAssetWorkerKey = w.WorkerEmailNm
    GROUP BY s.ServerKey,
             s.ServerNm
```

OR You could use left  join if there are not all matching

```
SELECT
  s.ServerKey,
  s.ServerNm,
  group_concat(w.WorkerIdsid)
FROM vw_dimserver s
LEFT JOIN vw_FactHardwareAssetContact c
  ON s.ServerKey = c.ServerKey
LEFT JOIN vw_DimWorker w
  ON c.HardwareAssetWorkerKey = w.WorkerEmailNm
GROUP BY s.ServerKey,
         s.ServerNm
```